# Generate textbox into grid from a string

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I would like to generate text boxes inside a gridview. Each of the text box contains a char from the string (this string is obtain from the text box Text Changed event handler).

```
Example:
string = hello,
I would like to generate 5 textboxes, each contains "h", "e", "l", "l", "o".
```

I have implemented the application myself, but i run into performance issues, the application is very laggy when the string length is > 30 chars (when i type inside the textbox, the textbox generates much slower than my input, besides my input is delay before it appears in the text box)

May I know how can I improve this problem? (i am quite sure, with today PC, this should not be a performance problem...)

Code:

```
 // main.cs
 private ObservableCollection<MenuSettings> gridCollection;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.gridCollection = new ObservableCollection<MenuSettings>();

            gridView.ItemsSource = this.gridCollection;            
        }

        private void textBox_name_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var collections = MenuSettings.Convert(textBox_name.Text);
            int gridCollectionLength = this.gridCollection.Count;
            int diff = collections.Count - gridCollectionLength;

            for (int i = 0; i < Math.Abs(diff); i++) {
                if (diff > 0) {
                    this.gridCollection.Add(new MenuSettings());
                } else {
                    this.gridCollection.RemoveAt(gridCollectionLength - i - 1);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < this.gridCollection.Count; i++) {
                this.gridCollection[i] = collections[i];
            }
        }

// menusetting.cs
 public class MenuSettings
    {
        private SolidColorBrush selected;

        public string Title { set; get; }
        public SolidColorBrush Selected { set; get; }


        public static List<MenuSettings> Convert(string text)
        {
            return text.ToCharArray().Select((x, i) => {
                return new MenuSettings()
                {
                    Title = x.ToString()
                };
            }).ToList();
        }
    }


<TextBox x:Name="textBox_name" Text="hello! this is so cool!"
                 TextChanged="textBox_name_TextChanged"
                 SelectionChanged="textBox_name_SelectionChanged" />
        <GridView x:Name="gridView">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MenuSettings">
                    <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Title}"
                             Background="{x:Bind Selected}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

Comment: Try clearing gridCollection at textBox_name_TextChanged method and populate the collection again. So that you will have only one "for" loop. I have suggested to create new MenuSettings every time because already you were creating new MenuSettings using Convert() method.

Comment: @VictoryJessie ty for ur suggestion! did that and i also disable the animation effect in the gridview item container style, i did gain better rendering, but i still got the sluggishness when the string length > 50... i am not sure i am doing this correctly or missing something, rendering what i required is definitely not a problem for such a small amount of data...

Comment: @Tim can you elloborate? correctly? you only want to generate textboxes on each character in a grid?

Comment: @user6002727 yes, generate textbox inside a grid, and each textbox contains a char from the string

Comment: Please try your text box generation using Dispatcher in Background priority